# Mysql Deadlock in SELECT.. if nothing exists INSERT

Tags: mysql, transactions, deadlock

I have a simple split testing table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tracked_split_test_track_variant` (
  `tracked_split_test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `track_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `variant` char(1) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`tracked_split_test_id`,`track_id`),
  KEY `tracked_split_test_track_variant_1` (`tracked_split_test_id`),
  KEY `tracked_split_test_track_variant_2` (`track_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tracked_split_test_track_variant_2` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) 
    REFERENCES `track` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tracked_split_test_track_variant_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`tracked_split_test_id`) 
    REFERENCES `tracked_split_test` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Where variant is a randomly A or B.

When the system asks 'Which variant should I show this user?' I want the following things to happen:

- `SELECT` the `tracked_split_test_track_variant` that belongs to the current `track` and `tracked_split_test`
- If no record exists create a new one with a random variant and `INSERT` it

Currently I'm running the `SELECT` and (optional) `INSERT` query in a transaction as:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM tracked_split_test_track_variant
     WHERE track_id = :track_id
       AND tracked_split_test_id = :tracked_split_test_id
FOR UPDATE
```

and

```
    INSERT 
      INTO tracked_split_test_track_variant
    VALUES (:track_id, :tracked_split_test_id, :variant)
```

I added the `FOR UPDATE` to the `SELECT` so that if two transactions were running with the same details.. I wouldn't get two `INSERT` attempts.

Even though I commit as soon as possible, I'm now getting deadlocks instead. Have I done this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the tuples are immutable outside of this transaction, I have come up with the following solution using explicit named locks:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('tracked_split_test_track_variant-xxx-yyy',30);

SELECT * 
  FROM tracked_split_test_track_variant
 WHERE tracked_split_test_id = :tracked_split_test_id
   AND track_id = :track_id

     [
INSERT 
  INTO tracked_split_test_track_variant
VALUES (:track_id, :tracked_split_test_id, :variant)
     ]

    DO RELEASE_LOCK('tracked_split_test_track_variant-xxx-yyy');
```

Where `xxx` is the `tracked_split_test_id` and `yyy` is the `track_id`

I would be interested to see if there is a better solution out there however.